# Array of email case insensitive searching

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, search

I have an array of strings,string in the sense email id's... so i need to check whether the array contains the email id which i'm giving....also need to check case insensitive....currently i'm using following code for that

```
 if ([arrayAllEmail containsObject:email])
{
// do some stuff here...
}
```

the problem is the suppose the arraAllEmail contains Abc@gmail.com....but i'm giving (email = abc@gmail.com)abc@gmail.com for checking purpose to it'll return "NO" as a result...that's why i need  case insensitive searching mechanism.... so anyone know how to solve this issue pls give me answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two different approaches can fix this problem:

- Convert strings to the same case (upper or lower, you decide) before placing them into the array. Do the same on the search string to ensure that the result is found case-insensitively, or
- Use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method, and put a case-insensitive comparison inside the test block.

Here is how to implement the second approach:

```
if ([arrayAllEmail indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [email caseInsensitiveCompare:obj] == NSOrderedSame;
}] != NSNotFound) {
    // do some stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
-(bool) array: (NSArray*) anArray containsAddress: (NSString*) emailAddresss
{
    return [array indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
               {
                   return [obj caseInsensitiveCompare: emailAddress] == NSOrderedSame;
               }
           ] != NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me

Comment: @RDC That's because of the bug with the missing `== NSOrderedSame` that I am adding back

Answer (score 1):

```
if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"some string"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
    // strings are equal except for possibly case
}
```

here you can pass your search term and otherside array with objectindex.

if you need any further help let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try in simply way below

```
   for(NSString *str in arrayAllEmail)
{
     if([str uppercaseString]     
      isEqualToString:[email uppercaseString]]
       // strings are equal except for possibly case
       }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, arrayAllEmail is an array. An NSArray does not respond to selector uppercaseString. This will crash the app.

Comment: Thanks for updating me i did not notice only that it is an array:) hence updated the same, Please follow